# Find Specific Heat of ice Using Virtual-lab Calorimetry

Tags: thermodynamics

I'm trying to use this virtual laboratory
https://media.pearsoncmg.com/bc/bc_0media_chem/chem_sim/calorimetry/Calor.php

and try to calculate the specific heat capacity of ice. Based on Virtual lab when I tick on "show specific heat capacity" it shows $2.06 ~ \frac{\text{J}}{\text{g C}}$.

**How to get $\mathbf{2.06 \frac{J}{g ~ C}}$?**

**i have tried using the equation $\mathbf{m c \Delta T_\text{ice}  = m c \Delta T_\text{water}}$ but got $\mathbf{16 \frac{J}{g ~ C}}$**

maybe i have a little misconception about this

note : I set

- Substance [1] = ice ($H_{2}O$) with mass $50\ \text{g}$ and initial temperature $-20\ \text{°C}$
- Substance [2] = water ($H_{2}O$) with a mass of $100 g$ and an initial
  temperature of $50\ \text{°C}$.
- the final temperature is $3.43$ in the virtual

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not take in account, that the ice melts, so you need most of the energy for the heat of fusion which is 334J/g for ice from 0°C ice to 0°C water

Comment: thanks sir, got it 2.066444, by adding as you described

mcΔT+mL+mcΔT=mcΔT

I need to study this chapter more fully next time